# Why does the installation of Ubuntu 18.04 with LVM and more than one Logical Volume fail into initramfs?

Tags: server, partitioning, 18.04, system-installation, lvm

My setup is an qemu/KVM host which I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on.

I want to have only /boot outside the LVM, and the rest of my filesystems (like /usr, /home, /root, /var) inside my Volume Group.

This was possible with 16.04, but for this release I don't see a way to do the same.

In the help tutorial [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html.en#lvm) only the possibility of something outside of the standard filesytems is described.

As coming to the manual setup for LVM it is possible to create an own volume group, with logical volumes in it and filesystems on them.

But if you choose to use more than the root filesystem '/', after a reboot it goes into the initramfs mode and you're lost.

I also tried to make '/' a normal ext4 partition and let /usr, /home etc. go into a volume group, but that came also to the same effect.

Coming to partitioning I did:

- Choose to 'Make a boot device'
- Added /boot as ext4
- Added the rest of the disk as unformatted space.
  That was the only sensible offering in the menu. Maybe there should be
  something like 'Use as LVM' there?

[Giving space to LVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4vsA.png)

- Then 'Create Volume Group'

[Creating the volume group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkRHc.png)

- Adding some more LVs (for '/', '/usr', '/home', '/tmp'

[Adding LVs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6bDQ.png)

- Hit done and let the rest of the installation run

The effect in all described scenarios is the same:
The system goes into initramfs like this:

[After reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01fAm.png)

So I booted into the machine with a live cd and that showed me that
it was all there:

[gParted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUGUz.png)

But in the /etc/fstab everything had the same UUID, which is an obvious mistake.

[fstab with UUIDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDHwz.png)

The only way to make this work was to exchange the UUIDs with the paths to the logical volumes.

[changed fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04EkA.png)

**That might work for now, but any further LVM operations on one of that logical volumes will get confused**.

So the only thing I can really do by now is installing a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and do a release upgrade.

Can someone help to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Works as usual here. How are you trying to install Ubuntu? (And anyway `/usr` should be in `/`; making it a separate filesystem is not really supported since a long time ago. You can put `/home` and `/opt` on separate filesystems.)

Comment: My setup is an ubuntu desktop 18.04 with KVM/QEMU on it as virtualization engine.
I use virt-manager to setup new hosts.

I do not know since when it is not supported any more putting /usr into a separate filesystem, if so I must have missed that in the release notes.
(Ist it really? Since when?)
I could understand if that was not recommended, but In my case I need it to keep my clients and users installing things until it bumps into the boundaries (education environment lab).

Comment: For example, [Separate `/usr` is broken](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/) on Freedesktop.org.

Comment: @Melebius: I added the link to Viceldan's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried it with not having a separate `/usr` and it worked.
So AlexP's comments and link were leading to the correct conclusion:

**Don't have a separate `/usr` filesystem.**

See [Separate /usr is broken](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/) on Freedesktop.org for details.